# Use ifelse function when extracting data from pdfs

Tags: r, regex, string, text, stringr

I'm trying to extract part of a PDF document. There are different car models with pricing and when a document uses a lowercase instead of an uppercase letter, I don't know how to extract the dollar amount. I think an `ifelse` statement would work fine but I'm having difficulty writing it. An example of the data is below:

```
$1500 Chevy
$2800 Ford
$1200 Subaru
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
Model <- as.numeric(str_match(f[1], "\\$(\\d+)\\s\\Ford|ford"))[[2]])
```

Comment: Try with `[A-Za-z]+` instead of referring each car model or if you want `(?i)ford` to make it case-insensitive after the `\\s` i.e. `f <- c("$1500 Chevy", "$2800 Ford", "$1200 ford");str_match(f, "\\$(\\d+)\\s(?i)ford")[,2]#
[1] NA     "2800" "1200"`

Comment: That worked perfectly! I've been working on this on and off for a few weeks when I had free time. I appreciate your help lol

Comment: Though, if I do use an ifelse statement in the future, such as wanting to pull the dollar amount for either a ford or chevy, would that be easy with regex and strings?

Comment: You can use the `|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make it case-insensitive with `(?i)`

```
as.numeric(str_match(v1, "\\$(\\d+)\\s(?i)ford")[,2])
#[1]   NA 2800 1200
```

If we need either 'Ford' or 'Chevy'

```
as.numeric(str_match(v1, "\\$(\\d+)\\s(?i)(ford|chevy)")[,2])
#[1] 1500 2800 1200
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("$1500 Chevy", "$2800 Ford", "$1200 ford")
```